# JsTree : How to get event when dropping node from a tree to a second tree?

Tags: javascript, jstree

I've read the documentation but I didn't find the solution.

Here's an simple example where I want to catch the event when I drop in tree_1 a node from tree_2:
http://jsfiddle.net/superjames/fumkdwqy/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li data-jstree='{"opened":true}'>First tree
      <ul>
        <li>Child node 1</li>
        <li>Child node 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br/><br/><br/>
<div id="container_2">
  <ul>
    <li data-jstree='{"opened":true}'>Second tree
      <ul>
        <li>Child node 3</li>
        <li>Child node 4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#container').jstree({
  "core" : { "check_callback" : true }, // so that operations work
  "plugins" : ["dnd"]
});

$('#container_2').jstree({
  "core" : { "check_callback" : true }, // so that operations work
  "plugins" : ["dnd"]
});
```

Comment: where the callbacks for "drop_finish"?
http://old.jstree.com/documentation/dnd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
.on("copy_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
    alert(1);
})
```

Source : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jstree/mrf6fY5d5JA